# Regular expression to extract only numbers but only if string doesn't contain any letters

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to extract digits from the string that may contain some special characters (let's say "+-() ") but not any other characters, i.e.:

```
"+123 (456) 7-8" -> "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8" is extracted
"123a45" -> pattern matching fails, nothing is extracted
"1234 B" -> pattern matching fails, nothing is extracted
```

Comment: Ok, so write a regular expression that does that.

Comment: ...I took that out for a reason, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/248731

Comment: I've tried to play with the solution from somewhat similar question: [Regular expression to match line that doesn't contain a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) but without much luck. I can get pattern matching to fail if any letter appears but I can't extract only digits if sting also contains " -()+" characters...

Comment: Showing failed attempts makes downvotes less likely: People want to teach you what you've done wrong, rather than just give you code as though SO were a code writing service.

Comment: Looking on the possible solutions below I've decided to divide task in parts: first check the string for letters via `\p{L}` and if string pass this check I can extract all digits with simple `\d` or  `[0-9]` expression...

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible with gnu sed like this:

```
sed -r -n '/^[-+0-9() ]+$/ {s/[^0-9]//g; s/([0-9])/\1, /g; p;}' file
```

- the re `^[-+0-9() ]+$` matches your lines, that should work in other re tools
- the part inside the `{ ... }` creates your formated output, you need to adopt that to your tool

Answer (score 0):

Free code here :

`.*[^\d^+^(^)^\-^\s]+.*(?:\d)|(?:\d)(?=.*[^\d^+^(^)^\-^\s]+.*)|(\d)`

Explanation:
`[^\d^+^(^)^\-^\s]` matches other characters except "+-() " and number

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF1nL2/1)